# best rigs for installing Elementaty OS

Tags: system-installation, hardware

So i was checking dell.com store and they sell a lot of laptops with Ubuntu as default OS, I was wondering if there is any good machine out there for elementary OS i have a Dell XPS 15 9530 and it runs okay, but suddenly the screen zooms  like X50 and I only see like 10 characters on my screen, so it has video card issues i guess, any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the graphics drivers. I recently bought a new Dell Inspiron 15 (5559) and had some issues which, however, could be solved by installing the newest kernel which includes newer graphics drivers.

If your machine is fairly new (or if you're planning to buy a new Dell machine) and has an Intel Skylake CPU, upgrading the kernel to version 4.3. or newer might help. For instructions to update to kernel 4.4 see here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for the tip man! I will check it out, I have been trying to have a stable Linux based machine to move 100% to develop software in Linux, but I have not managed too. I will check this Kernel thing and post the results back.  How is it running on the Dell inspiron 15  (5559) ? stable ?

Comment: OK great! Let me know the results. freya runs fast and smooth on my new Dell Inspiron, but even with the newest kernel there are still some graphical glitches at times. Nothing serious, but a little annoying. Looks like the graphics drivers for the Intel Skylake chipsets aren't fully developed yet, but I guess they'll solve that problem in the future (I hope!) :)

Comment: If you're interested, this was my problem: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/dell-inspiron-15-5559-problem-at-shutdown-and-logout-intel-skylake

Comment: So when i did the kernel update the display started working 100% fine no problems. However the wireless card is now not working at all. it is a bcm 4352 and all the tutorials i followed until now by chili555 are not working for me. Though to work with linux .... though