# Elementary OS is unstable when using with a 6th Gen CPU

Tags: graphic-drivers, kernel, intel, crash

I just got a new 6th Gen machine and installed Elementary OS in it. Things are a lot unstable. VLC crash, my editor Brackets crash, system hangs. Might be related to graphics? Im not using an external GPU. How can I fix this? Update the kernel? The intel graphic drivers?

Comment: Update the kernel to 4.4

Answer (score 2):

Running the command `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily` will upgrade your Kernel to 4.2, which solved many of my issues with Skylake.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a new 6th gen. machine (does this sound familiar to you?): [Dell Inspiron 15 5559 Problem at shutdown and logout (Intel Skylake)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/dell-inspiron-15-5559-problem-at-shutdown-and-logout-intel-skylake)

And it looks like it was a problem with the Intel graphics drivers. An update to kernel 4.4 solved it (almost). Here's how to upgrade: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu/