# Elementary freya won't shut down/restart without having to use the power button

Tags: shutdown

I'm a new user to elementary freya and am really enjoying it - I have installed it on my HP 350 G2 (it's the only os on the laptop) The issue I'm having is it won't shutdown/restart without me having to press the power button.

I have editing the grub file `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"` which fixing the shutting down/restart issue completely but it interfered with the sleep function. Once 'nomodeset' had been added the screen didn't wake up after i opened the lid. I've also tried - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off quiet splash"` which stopped the WiFi working and disabled one of the USB ports. And I've also tried `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pic=nomsi"` which also seemed to fix the shutting down issue but disabled the 2 other 3.0 usb ports.

I would really appreciate it if anyone help me with this line of code to get Elementary to close down cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search has revealed that your laptop has an AMD Radeon R5 M240 graphics card? If that is true, the problem probably is driver related, I had the same problem with an AMD Radeon R5 M335, none of the changes you mentioned would work. I fixed it by activating the proprietary fglrx driver for AMD video cards in the additional drivers tab of the update settings instead of the open source xorg drivers that were activated by default. After that there was no need to make changes to the grub file at all.

Check this post: [Dell Inspiron 15 5559 Problem at shutdown and logout (Intel Skylake)](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4281/dell-inspiron-15-5559-problem-at-shutdown-and-logout-intel-skylake/4354#4354)

If this sounds familiar to you, you're probably good with activating the mentioned driver.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've cracked it!!!

I've just enabled one of the other drivers on the additional driver list and it's closing down/restarting perfectly!

It's slightly slow to for the screen to wake up after sleep so I may try the third driver option (although I'm a little worried that I may lose the screen completely if the drivers wrong...)

But This is brilliant - thanks for much!

Comment: No probs! Upvote and mark as answered please, so other users can profit :) 

I don't think you will lose the screen completely because your Intel i5 chipset also has a video unit

Comment: and yeah I'm experiencing a slightly sluggish behavior on wakeup too, also when watching videos in Firefox. the driver doesn't seem to be perfect yet. I wonder when AMD will publish the new drivers that are expected to replace fglrx...

Comment: It's saying that I need a rep of 15 before I can upvote - so I'll have to come back and vote when I get my numbers up. But once again I really appreciate your help with this. I'm loving using Elementary so sorting this just adds to my appreciation of the work that has gone in to putting Freya together.

Comment: No worries, just keep on going with freya :) btw. the sluggish behavior has gotten a LOT better with the new firefox 46.0 which features gtk3 integration. progress is progressing!! :)

Comment: Is it **fglrx** . My laptop with that driver takes about 10 seconds to wake up